# Child elements are going out of parent element

Tags: html, css

In the below two screenshots, you can see the weird behavior of div.header ( parent ) and ul, li( child ) .

Due to this weird behavior, **newer content**(span,) in placed in the **mid of the page.** It's like the menu bar is not inside of header as it is supposed to be.

screenshots are below HTML and CSS codes:-

HTML:-

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="header-image"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="left-menu">
                            <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
 
                        <ul class="right-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">+91 964941****</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
        </div>
 
        <div class="content-a">
            <span>DEMO SESSIONS</span>
            <h1>Get Demo Class Now</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:-**

```
body{
    background-color:#191C26;
    color:white;
}
 
.header{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.header-image{
    width:10%;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:36px;
}
 
.header-image img{
    width:100%;
}
 
.left-menu, .right-menu{
 
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 200%;
}
 
.left-menu a, .right-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
}
 
.left-menu{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:12%;
}
 
.left-menu li{
    float:left;
  
}
 
.left-menu a{
  margin-right:20px;
}
.right-menu{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}
 
.right-menu li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
 
.right-menu a{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

[image]

2nd image:-
[image]

Comment: Can you include a mock up of or describe what your expected outcome should look like? What do you expect it to appear as when there is more content than available width?

Comment: Your `.header-image` class have the relative position and you've given it `top:36px`. That would make it move 36px from the top and would still take space and affect other elements as it it positioned relative. More on positions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many CSS frameworks like `bootstrap, tailwind etc` that can solve your problem and reduce lines of code. But if you want to create your own CSS then you can do this with `flexbox` and `CSS grid system`.

In your code adding `display: inline-block; width: 100%;` to your `header` class will fix your issue. Also use `float` only to main `ul` not `li`. I've made a little tweak to your code as below.

```css
body{
    background-color:#191C26;
    color:white;
}
 
.header{
    margin-top:20px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-image{
    width:10%;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:36px;
}
 
.header-image img{
    width:100%;
}
 
.left-menu, .right-menu{
 
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 200%;
}
 
.left-menu a, .right-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
}
 
.left-menu{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:12%;
}
 
.left-menu li{
    float:left;
  
}
 
.left-menu a{
  margin-right:20px;
}
.right-menu{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}
 
.right-menu li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
 
.right-menu a{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="header-image"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="left-menu">
                            <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
 
                        <ul class="right-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">+91 964941****</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
        </div>
 
        <div class="content-a">
            <span>DEMO SESSIONS</span>
            <h1>Get Demo Class Now</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-a">
            <span>DEMO SESSIONS</span>
            <h1>Get Demo Class Now</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "Also use float only to main ul not li. " Then I should use inline-block property to li items for making them sit in a single line?? just like a float left property

Answer (score 0):

I do not sure your request, but i make this, try this maybe will work for you

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #191c26;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 0.7rem;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content-a {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-image"><img src="images/logo.png"          alt="logo" /></div>

      <nav>
        <ul class="left-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right-menu">
          <li><a href="#">+91 964941****</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content-a">
      <span>DEMO SESSIONS</span>
      <h1>Get Demo Class Now</h1>
    </div>
```